# Minecraft runs really weird in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ati, graphics, games, performance, minecraft

When I have Vsync on my framerate is capped to 30 instead of 60. Also, when I go fullscreen the mouse seems to have really fast acceleration and the game looks really jumpy. I could run this on Windows fine.

AMD Athlon II x2 250 3.0GHz
8 GB RAM
AMD Radeon HD 7750 GDDR5 1GB.

Do I need to install some other graphics driver?